# Flutter BlocConsumer doesn't listen to state change when searching

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have been battling with this flutter bloc problem. I am currently using flutter Bloc 7.0.1. The BlocConsumer doesn't listen to the state changes at all. Anytime I enter values inside the search field, event is been called and state is yielded but the listener fail to listen to state changes.

This issue is really driving me mad.

**STATE**

```
part of 'people_bloc.dart';
@immutable
abstract class PeopleState {}

class PeopleInitial extends PeopleState {}

class PeopleLoadingState extends PeopleState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class SearchLoadingState extends PeopleState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}
```

**BLOC**

```
List<SearchPeopleResponseData> people = [];
  @override
  Stream<PeopleState> mapEventToState(
    PeopleEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is SearchPeopleEvent) {
      yield SearchLoadingState();
      try {
        var token = await getToken();
        //print(token);
        SearchPeopleResponse responseData =
            await client.getPeople(token!, event.term);

        if (responseData.status == 200) {
          yield GetSearchResultState(getPeopleResponse: responseData);
        } else {
          yield PeopleErrorState(message: responseData.msg);
          print("loadingE");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        //print("error msg here ${e.toString()}");
        PeopleErrorState(message: e.toString());
      }
    }
```

**EVENT**

```
part of 'people_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class PeopleEvent {
  const PeopleEvent();
}

class GetPeopleEvent extends PeopleEvent {
  final String term;
  GetPeopleEvent({required this.term});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [term];
}

class SearchPeopleEvent extends PeopleEvent {
  final String term;
  SearchPeopleEvent({required this.term});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [term];
}
```

**VIEW**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<PeopleBloc, PeopleState>(
                listener: (context, state) {
        print("Listener has been called");
        if (state is GetSearchResultState) {
          loading = false;
          print("Result Found in view");
        } else if (state is SearchLoadingState) {
          loading = true;
          print("Search loading");
        } else if (state is PeopleLoadingState) {
          loading = true;
        }
```

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhJDs.png)

Comment: you need to provide your code and more detail. We can't help you otherwise

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am still in need of a solution to the above code problem